# How to create a FAQ page answer disappearing appearing with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a FAQ page with a few questions, however the answeres should appear and disappear depending on a click on a plus or minus image..

code:

```
<div id ="faqmain">
    <div class ="faqquestion">   
        <img class ="faqq" src="/Content/img/FAQQ.png">
        <img class = "faqplus" src="/Content/img/FAQplus.png">
        <div class = "question">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec.
            </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "faqanswer">
        <img class ="faqq" src="/Content/img/FAQa.png">
        <div class = "question">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "How to create a FAQ page answer disappearing appearing with JQuery?" i guess :)

Comment: If you demonstrate some effort - ie by including your current jQuery code people will provide some specific answers - asking for a solution isnt the right way to get help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method. It hide if the element is currently visible, otherwise it shows the hidden element.

Hide MINUS images for all questions.

Hide text of all questions using display:none style.

```
<div class = "question" style="display:none">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec.
            </p> 
</div>
```

Then On click on PLUS or MINUS image, call the toggle method on relevant div. (assuming MINUS image has a css class called "faqminus").

```
$(".faqplus").click(
function(){
 $(this).toggle();
 $(this).parent().find(".faqminus").toggle();
 $(this).parent().find(".question").toggle();
}
);

$(".faqminus").click(
function(){
 $(this).toggle();
 $(this).parent().find(".faqplus").toggle();
 $(this).parent().find(".question").toggle();
}
);
```

EDIT: See this code in action in http://jsfiddle.net/wFQ7U/

Comment: @Beginner See http://jsfiddle.net/wFQ7U/  I used this same code as I mentioned in the post. Check the link.

Answer (score 1):

Using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can accomplish this with a simple click bind. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQehF/)

```
$('#faqmain').on('click','.faqquestion',function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

with

```
.faqanswer{display:none}
```

Best practice would be to make the "plus" icon the effect of a class on something, then you could also toggle the plus and minus without having to swap an image in and out.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some helpful links:
http://www.madeincima.it/en/articles/jquery-tutorial-fancy-faqs/
http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-sliders
http://www.bitrepository.com/fancy-faq.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.faqplus').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.faqanswer').toggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82vWd/

Comment: the plus image does not turn into minus#